# How to add a comment box in a view so that users can comment on it just like it displays in node

Tags: 7, views

I want to add a comment box in a view so that user can comment there also just like they do in specific node.

Comment: What version of Drupal?

Comment: I am using drupal 7

Comment: Ahh, I don't know how you would do it with D7. Sorry.

Comment: okay. No problem. You know with drupal 8

Answer (score 0):

You can create a *block* display of the View, add that block to a node, and activate comments on that node.